# Eclipse project management with SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, project

As we work in team today, and we use different OSes, is it possible to manage a Eclipse project through different plateforms (Windows, Mac OS X and Linux), and with different SVN clients ?

If we put all files of the (Java) project, the bin subdirectory and metadata files comes in conflict, teamworkers can't import project localy, etc.

Any best practices / ideas to manage this ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can install an eclipse svn client such as subversive or subclipse, but it's also possible to manage the connection to the repository externally with a separate client such as tortoise etc.

as a general rule, we don't add .class files to the repository, and ignore the whole 'bin' directory (or equiv).

besides that i'm not sure what you're asking.